# How to convert a Scientific notation to number in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Ex:- For example we are uploading a sheet with mobile call details. which is having one field called “dialed number “. It might be more than 10 digits some times and the same has been converting  to Scientific notations in the excel sheets and the same we are uploading to the database.  How to convert this scientific notation to numbers in the database.
Kindly help me by providing the possible ways to convert the Scientific notation to Number. Please let me know if any some more information needed.

Comment: Don't corrupt the data in Excel first...

Comment: My intention is to chagne the Scientific values to numbers in the database. Kindly suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

Excel does not change the actual value of a cell, it just displays it in the scientific notation.
Have you actually tried to import data from excel into SQL Server?

Comment: Yes i uploaded the same. I am not sure whether excel is changing the data or not, But i found the scientific numbers in the database.

Comment: How is data added to Excel file? How do you import this data into SQL Server (bcp, linked server, copy-paste, ...)?